# rpy2 RRuntimeError: Error in rep : invalid 'times' argument

Tags: python, r, python-xarray, rpy2

I'm running an R package in Python using `rpy2`. The function `rMBC.MBCn` originally uses matrices as inputs, which are **obs_dat**, **mod_dat**, and **mod_nf** arguments in this case. In order to run the function for a multidimensional data, I used `xarray.apply_ufunc` in Python to vectorize the `rMBC.MBCn` function. However, when I ran the script below, it caused a runtime error in `rep`. I'm not quite sure what caused this error. I think it might be because the structure of the data is quite different from it's original inputs in R? The variables aren't exactly being read as 'columns' because of the shape of the data? Also, from the R script `rep(trace.calc, ncol(o.c))`, the `o.c`  is the **obs_dat** in this case.

Here is a description of the input I used for **obs_dat** (It's similar to **mod_dat** and **proj_dat**) it contains 2 variaables with 3 dimensions each:

```
        <xarray.Dataset>
        Dimensions:    (latitude: 101, longitude: 101, time: 240)
        Coordinates:
          * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1986-01-16T11:00:00 ... 2005-12-16T11:00:00
          * longitude  (longitude) float32 110.0 110.25 110.5 ... 134.5 134.75 135.0
          * latitude   (latitude) float32 25.0 24.75 24.5 24.25 ... 0.75 0.5 0.25 0.0
        Data variables:
            rsns       (time, latitude, longitude) float32 102.40908 ... 186.72174
            tas        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 9.834406 ... 27.176416
        Attributes:
            CDI:          Climate Data Interface version 1.9.6 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/...
            Conventions:  CF-1.6
            history:      Wed Feb 24 14:45:36 2021: cdo merge ../OBS/ERA5_ssr_1986-20...
            frequency:    mon
            CDO:          Climate Data Operators version 1.9.6 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/...
```

Here's the script that I ran using `rpy2` and `xarray` for `rMBC.MBCn` and the error that came after.

```
    import xarray as xr
    import numpy as np
    from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
    from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
    
    pandas2ri.activate()
    rMBC = importr("MBC")
    
    def MBCn_hist(obs_dat,mod_dat,mod_nf):
        mbc = rMBC.MBCn(obs_dat,mod_dat,mod_nf,2,qmap_precalc=False,ratio_seq=np.repeat(False,2))[0]
        return(mbc)
    
    hist2 = xr.apply_ufunc(MBCn_hist, obs.drop('time'), hist.drop('time'), proj.drop('time'),
                          input_core_dims=[['time'],['time'],['time']],
                          output_core_dims=[['time']], vectorize=True,dask='parallelized')
```

> `RRuntimeError: Error in rep(trace.calc, ncol(o.c)) : invalid 'times' argument`

Answer (score 0):

With rpy2, exceptions of type `RRuntimeError` are R errors (errors that cause R to stop during the evaluation of code). Here this seems to be when `rMBC.MBCn()` is called. The error message itself comes from the R code (in that case the R library `MBC`).

I suggest you first try to get your call working without `xarray` (use a subset of the data). Reasons to do so are:

- it will make it easier to check what is happening with the conversions Python<->R (and fine-tune it if needed)
- parallelization needs to be handled with care. R is largely unable to handle multithreading, and multiprocessing sometimes need a bit of care (the R shared C library uses global variables to store things like state and call stack - depending on how the child processes are created there might be more shared between them than is wanted).

Besides that the use of `pandas2ri.activate()` is discouraged (and it is deprecated). Use a localconverter instead.

The rpy2 documentation has more details or examples about the above.